# Can we reduce the diophantine equation $x^4+4y^4=z^2$ to $x^4+y^4=z^2$ to show there is no nontrivial solution?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

Is it possible to reduce the diophantine equation
$$x^4+4y^4=z^2,$$
to the diophantine equation
$$x^4+y^4=z^2,$$
to show that there is no nontrivial solution?

Please assume the second equation is already known to have only trivial solutions.

I think Fermats descent can prove this, but I hope there is an easier way.

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ integers?

Comment: The question body is kinda terse. We prefer questions where reader is able to understand the question without reading the title. Do read [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443590/on-the-diophantine-equation-x44y4-zp for the more general equation $x^4+4y^4=z^p$ for all primes $p$.

Answer (score 5):

> TL;DR We can reduce the given diophantine equation to the well-known diophantine equation
>   $$X^4-Y^4=Z^2,$$
>   which also has no nontrivial solutions. Given that any proof of this (that I know) is significantly different and more involved than the proof that the diophantine equation
>   $$X^4+Y^4=Z^2,$$
>   has no nontrivial solutions, my answer is: **"No, not in a sensible way."**

---

A *nontrivial* solution to the diophantine equation
$$X^4+4Y^4=Z^2,\tag{1}$$
is a triplet $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{Z}^3$ satisfying the equation with $xyz\neq0$. We will show that no nontrivial solution exists.

Let $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{Z}^3$ be a solution to $(1)$. After changing signs if necessary we have $x,y,z\geq0$.

**Observation 1:** Without loss of generality $\gcd(x,y)=1$.

*Proof.*
Let $d:=\gcd(x,y)$ so that $d^4$ divides
$$x^4+4y^4=z^2,$$
and hence $d^2$ divides $z$. Setting $u:=\tfrac xd$, $v:=\tfrac yd$ and $w:=\tfrac{z}{d^2}$ we get another solution $(u,v,w)\in\Bbb{Z}^3$ to equation $(1)$, and we have $\gcd(u,v)=1$.$\qquad\square$

**Observation 2:** Without loss of generality $x$ and $z$ are odd, and $y$ is even.

*Proof.* Reducing mod $2$ shows that $x\equiv z\pmod{2}$. If both are odd then reducing mod $8$ shows that $y$ is even, and we are done. If both are even then setting $u:=\tfrac x2$ and $w=\tfrac z2$ shows that
$$4u^4+y^4=w^2,$$
and so $(y,u,w)\in\Bbb{Z}^3$ is another solution. As before $y\equiv w\pmod{2}$, and because $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and $x$ is even, we find that $y$ and $w$ are odd, and then as before $u$ is even.$\qquad\square$

**Theorem:** There are no nontrivial solutions to the diophantine equation
$$X^4-Y^4=Z^2.$$

*Proof.* This is theorem 114 on page 227 of *Introduction to number theory* by T. Nagell.

**Observation 3:** The solution $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{Z}^3$ is trivial.

*Proof.* Because the triplet $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{Z}^3$ satisfies equation $(1)$ we also have
$$x^4=z^2-4y^4=(z+2y^2)(z-2y^2).$$
Let $d$ denote the $\gcd$ of the two factors on the right hand side. Then $d$ divides the difference $4y^2$ and the product $x^4$ of the two factors. Because $x$ is odd and $\gcd(x,y)=1$ it follows that $d=1$. This means both factors are fourth powers, say
$$z+2y^2=u^4\qquad\text{ and }\qquad z-2y^2=v^4,$$
for some $u,v,\in\Bbb{Z}$. Then $(u,v,2y)\in\Bbb{Z}^3$ is a solution to the diophantine equation
$$X^4-Y^4=Z^2.$$
Then $uvy=0$, and if any of these three equals $0$ it is not hard to see that $xyz=0$.$\qquad\square$

**Conclusion:** From an arbitrary solution $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{Z}^3$ we have constructed a solution that turns out to be trivial. Tracing the construction back shows that the original solution is itself trivial. Hence there exist no nontrivial solutions to the diophantine equation $(1)$.